# Compare Two Arrays And Delete Same (Intersect) Value From Second Array

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, intersection

```
       string[] one={"my", "5", "two", "array", "hey?", "good", "day"};
       string[] two={"hello!", "how", "good", "day", "us", "very", "two", "hard", "learn", "it"};
```

For example: I have these above arrays and I want to compare them, after comparison remove same values from string[] two. So, when I compile to code my arrays will be like this;

```
       string[] one={"my", "5", "two", "array", "hey?", "good", "day"};
       string[] two={"hello!", "how", "us", "very", "hard", "learn", "it"};
```

Note: I couldn't produce any idea for it, sorry.

Comment: So you just want to modify array `two` ?

Comment: Yes sir. I just want modify array two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use, `Where`, `Contains`, in a `Linq` statement then `ToArray`

In simple terms,

1. It filters array `two` by checking if array `one` does not contain each element of two
2. Converts the output back to an array
3. Assigns its back to your variable `two`

**Example**

```
string[] one={"my", "5", "two", "array", "hey?", "good", "day"};
string[] two = { "hello!", "how", "good", "day", "us", "very", "two", "hard", "learn", "it" };

two = two.Where(x => !one.Contains(x)).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", two));
```

***Note***, This is case sensitive

**Output**

```
hello!,how,us,very,hard,learn,it
```

---

Or a more performant way is to use `Except`, which i totally forgot about (thanks to comments)

```
two = two.Except(one).ToArray();
```

---

[Enumerable.Except Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

[Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

[Enumerable.Contains Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element.

[Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates an array from a IEnumerable.

Comment: After this code, can I use "two" like an array?

Comment: @heymycoder yes

Comment: Seems like `.Contains(x)` is going to result in a quadratic time complexity. Making `one` into a set would make it linear.

Comment: @ggorlen yes it will be quadratic, or less

Comment: Looks like a "sub-optimal" implementation of `.Except`... Any particular reason you believe it is better approach?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i was just writing it up

Comment: @TheGeneral my question marked for reason duplicate, what should I do?

Comment: @heymycoder its fine, the community will take care for it, your work here is done

Comment: @TheGeneral OK. Thank you again.